# How to correctly implement the UserDetailsService without having an username?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, userdetailsservice

I am creating an oauth service in spring-boot and want to use user information from a MariaDB for authentication.
When implementing UserDetailsService I have to override the function loadUserByUsername. The problem is that my user model does not have a field username, instead of this I want to load the users using their mail address.
So my question: How do I correctly implement the UserDetailsService without having an username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the mail address *is* the user name.

It is just a **text value that uniquely identify the user** with the domain. It can be a:

- login name *(domain: application)*
- email address *(domain: global)*
- SSN *(domain: US resident)*
- student id *(domain: school)*
- employees id *(domain: company)*
- gamer id *(domain: game site)*
- or whatever you want it to be

as long as it is unique, so that `loadUserByUsername` can find exactly one record.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 can be you have to pass the emailId in username and field and use the emailId to validate in your Custom UserDetailsService

Option 2 you need to have some mapping using which you can derive the emailId from the username field.

```
@Component
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmailId(s.toLowerCase());
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("The username %s doesn't exist", s));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("STANDARD_USER"));

        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmailId(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```